# How to make a mobile html menu work on iOS devices

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, safari

I really don't know what should be the correct title for this question, but I have a custom menu I have created and using JQuery to toggle, it looks like this.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="user-info">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        <a class="inline" href="https://example.com/">account</a>
        <ul class="items">
            <li class="item">
                <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
                <a class="inline" href="https://example.com/register">Create Account</a>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <span class="fa fa-login"></span>
                <a class="inline" href="https://example.com/login">Account Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my CSS code

```
ul, ul li, ol, ol li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
@media (max-width: 540px) {
    #sidebar ul.menu {
        height: auto!important;
    }
}

#sidebar .menu { 
    height: calc(100vh - 94px);
    overflow: auto;
    transition: 200ms ease-out height;
}
@media (max-width: 540px) {
    #sidebar ul.menu li {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0!important;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 5px; 
        z-index: 111;
        height: 50px;
    }
}

#sidebar ul li { 
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media (max-width: 540px) {
    #sidebar ul.menu li ul {
        background: #222629;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(255 255 255 / 08%);
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 50px;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed!important;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: 200ms ease-in all;
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
}
#sidebar ul.menu li ul {
    background: #222629;
}
@media (max-width: 540px) {
    #sidebar ul.menu li.shown ul {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```

So far everything works well on all platforms except iOS although, I haven't tried on MAC, but I've tested across over 5 iOS devices including iOS 14.1 but the menu wont toggle when the `.shown` class is appended to the `li.user-info` item.
What am I doing wrongly?

**EDIT**:
I have updated my css to include this at the top:

```
#sidebar ul.menu li.shown ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Still doesn't work, I have also set `opacity:1` and `visibility:visible` and `display:block` in the above piece of code, still, nothing worked.

**Update:** There is no element with a `.menu_wrapper` class, there was a typo, I mistakenley copied css from my old code for this question, I had to come up with simpler naming conventions to aid debugging.

Comment: Can you show us the 'normal' CSS for .shown? At the moment the only .shown settings are within narrow viewports which wont apply to iPhones/iPads on the whole. There must be other CSS which sets opacity 1 outside of these narrow viewports.

Comment: @AHaworth Since the particular block of code had not been intended to modify the entire document I thought it unwise to apply it to the entire viewport, would you suggest that this is the cause or source of the problem?

Comment: What is the CSS styling for .shown when it's not in that media query? With the edit you have just made .shown stops it being shown.

Comment: @AHaworth there is no styling for ```.shown``` outside the media query. ```.shown``` is overwriting the the styling already declared in ```#sidebar ul.menu li ul```, so there was even no need fro the edit I just made.

Comment: What devices does your media query apply to?

Comment: The media query should apply to every smart phone.

Comment: True, unfortunately my only real IOS device is an iPad so I can't test properly.

Comment: This is just bad new for me.

Comment: Where does the element with id menu_wrapper sit and also the element with id sidebar? Could you make the HTML a little more complete?

Comment: Please take a look at the edit I made to the question, thanks